# How to read an NFC tag and beam it?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, nfc

I am trying to read an NFC card of an hotel(everything with their permission) and then beam this output to the door lock to open it. This is for a future project of an app for the hotel users.

I have tried very hard with React-Native but it seems impossible due to MifareClassic structure.

I have seen that to clone one nfc card of MifareClassic type you have to map all the keys of the memory which is illegal, but I am not trying to do that, I am just trying to save a signal and retramsmit it with the phone. Is it possible? How I can do that? Android native code?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is Host-based card emulation

[Host-based Card Emulation Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce)

Try this

Comment: If the hotel key card is based on MIFARE Classic we are talking about ISO 14443 Layer 3 communication.
This can't be emulated on a mobile phone with host card emulation.

Comment: @ErikM why can not be emulated?

Comment: Did you find any other solution? @HackFacilito